# Channel forms {error:my_field_name} with parameter error_handling="inline" doesn't display errors

Tags: safecracker, ee3

I cannot make {error:my_field_name} to work.  It is like it doesn't parse.
Here is my code :

```
{exp:channel:form channel="mychannel" return="test/index" error_handling="inline"}
<div>
        <label for="concerne">Concerne <span class="champs_requis">*</span></label>
        <div>{instructions:concerne}</div>
        <div class="error">{error:concerne}</div>
        {field:concerne}
    </div>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

If I use

```
{custom_fields}
{if error}<p class="error">{error}</p>{/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

it gives me error validation messages but I need manually constructed fields so I can't use {custom_fields} loop.

Is this happening to someone else (and I have to report the bug) or just me? If so, what am I doing wrong?

EE version : 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it was a bug of the EE version. The bug has been fixed in EE 3.3.3 release.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example you're using a `<div>` tag for the error styling but in the second code example you're using a `<p>` tag. I suggest inspecting your code to make sure CSS isn't hiding the .error class in your first code example.

Comment: I tried even with only {error:concerne} tag without encapsulating into html tags (div or p) but it doesn't give me any result...

Is that a bug of EE3 ?